# 'runThread' was not declared in this scope.

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a problem with that error and I literally have no idea how to solve this, how to call this function in main.cpp.

Snake.cpp

```
 void Snake::runThread(Snake* snake)
{
char c;
while(c != 'q'){
   timeout(50);
    c = getch();
    mx.lock();
    clear();
    drawBorder();
    snake->moveA();
    drawSnakes();
    refresh();
    mx.unlock();
}
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main() {



Snake *snake1;
Snake *snake2;

std::thread thread1 = std::thread(runThread, snake1);
std::thread thread2 = std::thread(runThreadB, snake2);

thread1.join();
thread2.join();

endwin();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably `std::thread(&Snake::runThread, snake1);`

Comment: It *isn't* declared in that scope, it is declared inside the `Snake` class. To get a pointer to a member function you use `&Snake::runThread`.

Comment: What is the exact error you get when running this? What have you already tried?

Comment: is runThread static or not?

Comment: @gchen runThread is not static.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way to do what it looks like you are trying to do is by getting rid of the argument in the `Snake::runThread` function (meaning you should also remove references to it within the function, e.g. `snake->MoveA();` should become `MoveA();`).

Then, in your main function, you can start the two snake threads by using

`std::thread thread1 = std::thread(&Snake::runThread, snake1);`

and

`std::thread thread2 = std::thread(&Snake::runThreadB, snake2);`

The existing `Snake` pointer parameter in the run thread function is redundant because you are already required to pass in an instance of a `Snake` to run the function by the `std::thread` constructor. If you were to go with this approach, make sure that your `Snake::runThread` function is not static (I can't tell if it is right now without seeing your header file).